# Unable to print using Ubuntu 20.04 and Xpress M2022

Tags: 20.04, printing

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 and I have a Samsung Xpress M2022 printer. But it doesn't seem to work. I downloaded the ppd file from the internet but that didn't work either. I then tried different ways to debug by searching online but nothing seemed to work. I am not sure how to go about finding the issue and how I can find the error log for this.

Doing `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u cups` gives me this output:

```
-- Logs begin at Mon 2020-08-10 15:38:06 BST, end at Thu 2020-10-15 20:33:12 BST. --
Oct 15 09:42:59 bishal-Latitude-7300 systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
Oct 15 11:52:00 bishal-Latitude-7300 /hpfax[11995]: [11995]: error: Failed to create /var/spool/cups/tmp/.hplip
Oct 15 20:30:28 bishal-Latitude-7300 cupsd[949]: pam_unix(cups:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Oct 15 20:30:28 bishal-Latitude-7300 cupsd[949]: pam_unix(cups:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Oct 15 20:30:39 bishal-Latitude-7300 cupsd[949]: pam_unix(cups:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Oct 15 20:30:39 bishal-Latitude-7300 cupsd[949]: pam_unix(cups:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Oct 15 20:30:40 bishal-Latitude-7300 cupsd[949]: pam_unix(cups:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Oct 15 20:30:40 bishal-Latitude-7300 cupsd[949]: pam_unix(cups:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Oct 15 20:30:45 bishal-Latitude-7300 cupsd[949]: pam_unix(cups:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Oct 15 20:30:45 bishal-Latitude-7300 cupsd[949]: pam_unix(cups:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Oct 15 20:30:47 bishal-Latitude-7300 cupsd[949]: pam_unix(cups:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Oct 15 20:30:47 bishal-Latitude-7300 cupsd[949]: pam_unix(cups:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Oct 15 20:30:52 bishal-Latitude-7300 cupsd[949]: pam_unix(cups:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Oct 15 20:30:52 bishal-Latitude-7300 cupsd[949]: pam_unix(cups:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Oct 15 20:30:53 bishal-Latitude-7300 cupsd[949]: pam_unix(cups:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Oct 15 20:30:53 bishal-Latitude-7300 cupsd[949]: pam_unix(cups:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
```

It is weird that it has something with hp even though my printer is a Samsung one.

### Edit:

I follow the instructions here for my USB printer: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems

Output of `tail -f /var/log/syslog`

```
Oct 15 11:52:40 bishal-Latitude-7300 kernel: [ 7789.814880] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: ZFCDB8GG3D0006B
Oct 15 11:52:40 bishal-Latitude-7300 kernel: [ 7789.819788] usblp 1-3:1.0: usblp1: USB Bidirectional printer dev 11 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x04E8 pid 0x3321
Oct 15 11:52:40 bishal-Latitude-7300 systemd[1]: Started Configure Plugged-In Printer.
Oct 15 11:52:40 bishal-Latitude-7300 udev-configure-printer: add usb-001-011
Oct 15 11:52:40 bishal-Latitude-7300 udev-configure-printer: device devpath is /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3
Oct 15 11:52:40 bishal-Latitude-7300 udev-configure-printer: Device already handled
Oct 15 11:52:40 bishal-Latitude-7300 systemd[1]: configure-printer@usb-001-011.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 15 11:52:40 bishal-Latitude-7300 systemd[1]: configure-printer@usb-001-011.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 15 11:53:07 bishal-Latitude-7300 kernel: [ 7817.391676] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 11
Oct 15 11:53:07 bishal-Latitude-7300 kernel: [ 7817.392059] usblp1: removed
Oct 15 11:53:35 bishal-Latitude-7300 kernel: [ 7845.614988] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
Oct 15 11:53:36 bishal-Latitude-7300 kernel: [ 7845.767530] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=3321, bcdDevice= 1.00
Oct 15 11:53:36 bishal-Latitude-7300 kernel: [ 7845.767533] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Oct 15 11:53:36 bishal-Latitude-7300 kernel: [ 7845.767534] usb 1-3: Product: M2020 Series
Oct 15 11:53:36 bishal-Latitude-7300 kernel: [ 7845.767536] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd.
Oct 15 11:53:36 bishal-Latitude-7300 kernel: [ 7845.767537] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: ZFCDB8GG3D0006B
Oct 15 11:53:36 bishal-Latitude-7300 kernel: [ 7845.772577] usblp 1-3:1.0: usblp1: USB Bidirectional printer dev 12 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x04E8 pid 0x3321
Oct 15 11:53:36 bishal-Latitude-7300 systemd[1]: Started Configure Plugged-In Printer.
Oct 15 11:53:36 bishal-Latitude-7300 udev-configure-printer: add usb-001-012
Oct 15 11:53:36 bishal-Latitude-7300 udev-configure-printer: device devpath is /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3
Oct 15 11:53:36 bishal-Latitude-7300 udev-configure-printer: Device already handled
Oct 15 11:53:36 bishal-Latitude-7300 systemd[1]: configure-printer@usb-001-012.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 15 11:53:36 bishal-Latitude-7300 systemd[1]: configure-printer@usb-001-012.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
^C
```

Output of `lsusb`

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0a5c:5843 Broadcom Corp. 58200
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:585b Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 04e8:3321 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd M2020 Series
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 062a:4101 MosArt Semiconductor Corp. Wireless Keyboard/Mouse
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0cf3:e007 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of `ls -l /dev/usb/lp* /dev/bus/usb/*/*`

```
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189,   0 Oct 15 09:42 /dev/bus/usb/001/001
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189,   2 Oct 15 09:42 /dev/bus/usb/001/003
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189,   5 Oct 15 09:42 /dev/bus/usb/001/006
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189,   6 Oct 15 09:42 /dev/bus/usb/001/007
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189,   7 Oct 15 09:42 /dev/bus/usb/001/008
crw-rw-r-- 1 root lp   189,  11 Oct 15 11:54 /dev/bus/usb/001/012
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 128 Oct 15 09:42 /dev/bus/usb/002/001
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 256 Oct 15 09:42 /dev/bus/usb/003/001
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 384 Oct 15 09:42 /dev/bus/usb/004/001
crw-rw---- 1 root lp   180,   1 Oct 15 11:54 /dev/usb/lp1
```

Output of `sudo usb_printerid /dev/usb/lp1`

```
GET_DEVICE_ID string:
MFG:Samsung;CMD:SPL,URF,FWV,PIC,EXT,DCU;MDL:M2020 Series;CLS:PRINTER;CID:SA_SPLV3_BW;MODE:SPL3,R000105;STATUS:BUSY;
```

Output of `lpinfo -v`

```
file cups-brf:/
direct hp
network http
network lpd
network ipp
network https
network beh
direct usb://Samsung/M2020%20Series?serial=ZFCDB8GG3D0006B
network socket
network ipps
direct hpfax
```

Output of `lsusb -v | grep -A 3 bInterfaceClass.*7`

```
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
      bInterfaceClass         7 Printer
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Printer
      bInterfaceProtocol      2 Bidirectional
      iInterface              0 
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
```

Output to `ls -l /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertospl`

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 92384 Sep 20 21:41 /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertospl
```

Comment: Look in `/var/log/cups` or ,`sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u cups`.

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" and "didn't work either" and "nothing seemed to work" are grossly inadequate problem descriptions

Comment: @waltinator thanks for mentioning how I should do this. Never done this before.

Comment: @waltinator Doing `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u cups` gives me this output:
-- Logs begin at Mon 2020-08-10 15:38:06 BST, end at Mon 2020-10-12 02:59:20 BST. --
Oct 10 09:21:04 bishal-Latitude-7300 systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
Oct 11 19:15:43 bishal-Latitude-7300 /hpfax[61971]: [61971]: error: Failed to create /var/spool/cups/tmp/.hplip

Comment: @Bishal Deb that output mentions hpfax and hplip. Those are software packages for HP printers, not for Samsung printers. Are you sure that a Samsung printer works with HP software? In Ubuntu 20.04 there is an issue with these HP software packages and they don't work.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should Edit your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: @Joe it is indeed bizarre that I see something with HP. I do not know why this is the case.

Comment: It would be really good if the printer is using a wireless connection and the output of `driverless` was given.

Comment: @brian_p the printer is not using a wireless connection

Comment: @Bishal Deb My comment was by way of a hint. Can you possibly get a wireless connection with the device and give `driverless`? From my point of view the situation should then become easier to deal with.

Comment: @brian_p I am not sure if this model can go wireless. There is no WPS button. I couldn't find anything on the internet. There is a similar model M2022w that can be connected wireless.

Comment: @waltinator I have done `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u cups` again after removing all the printers configured with my laptop and I got a different output. I have some additional lines now which say `Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
`

Comment: You are correct, Bishal; the printer is USB-only. I should have checked. This is a longshot: give the output of `lsusb -v | grep -A 3 bInterfaceClass.*7`

Comment: @brian_p I have added the output to the command you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, but no joy there. This PPD you downloaded from the internet should have lines for *NickName and *cupsFilter. What do they say?

Comment: `*cupsFilter:  "application/vnd.cups-raster 0 rastertospl"`  and `*NickName: "Samsung M2020 Series"`

Comment: Fine. You appear to have the correct PPD. Now do `ls -l /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertospl`.

Comment: I get `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 92384 Sep 20 21:41 /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertospl
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have M2022, but I have M2070W and I think you should be able to use official installer V1.00.39_01:17 downloaded from HP support site (HP - that isn't a mistake). You should try to download and unpack tar.gz file, enter the unpacked directory and run install.sh (I don't know if that is necessary, but I made it as root user). Then I go to CUPS localhost:631, deleted the auto installed printer and add it once again with the very first driver from the list. I'm able to add it via usb and wireless as well as the scanner.
If you try this way, write whether it works for you or not.
By the way, I think that Samsung's printer division was acquired in the meantime  by HP and now you should use Ubuntu drivers from HP site.

Comment: When I installed the install.sh file, I did not do it as a root user. I am guessing it was not properly done. I first ran uninstall.sh and then install.sh, both as  a root user this time and it did work. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The URI for this printer has been given as

> usb://Samsung/M2020%20Series?serial=ZFCDB8GG3D0006B

The user has a PPD somewhere on his system that has been indicated to be the correct one. The PPD's location is not known (but we can find out, if necessary).  The rastertospl filter is also on the system. This command sets up a print queue:

lpadmin -p 2022 -v URI -E -P /path/to.PPD

**Substitute** for **URI** from above. Then test with

```
lp -d 2022 /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I figured out that it was some problem with installing the ppd files. And so uninstalling and installing as a root user worked.